# How to emit tuple in diffrent for each loops and declare in single Fields method of storm bolt?

Tags: java, for-loop, apache-storm, bigdata

I'm getting the required strings from the tuple.My Strings are appended one so I’m splitting them and emitting in a for each loop.if I write a single emit (if I emit only "id")bolt shows no exceptions it works fine,but when I add one more for-each to split other strings and on emitting them bolt is throwing the exception as follow

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tuple created with wrong number of fields. Expected 2 fields but got 1 fields at backtype.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.<init>(TupleImpl.java:58) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707$bolt_emit__5736.invoke(executor.clj:739) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn$reify__5742.emit(executor.clj:763) at backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:203) at backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:63) at backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:101) at test.bolts.TInserts.execute(TInsert.java:264)
```

Here is Mybolt code

```
 public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
   try {
String screenname=tuple.getStringByField("s_name");
    String mentionname=tuple.getStringByField("n_name");
    String mentionid=tuple.getStringByField("n_id");

                 if(mentionid != null && !mentionid.isEmpty()){
                     for(String id:mentionid.split(",")){ 
                        id = id.trim();
                          this.collector.emit(new Values(id));
 this.collector.ack(tuple);
 }//for close
 }//if condtion for id
 if(mentionname != null && !mentionname.isEmpty()){
                     for(String mns:mentionname.split(",")){ 
                        mns = mns.trim();
                          this.collector.emit(new Values(mns));
this.collector.ack(tuple);
   }//for close
 }//if condtion for mentionname

  } //if close
    }
             catch (Exception e) {
           this.collector.reportError(e);
          this.collector.fail(tuple);
             }
       } 


@Override
   public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {

//   outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("id","mns"));//doesn't throw any   exception if i emit only id(1st for)                     
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("id","mns"));//thows exception 
}
}
```

How to emit id and mns in single emit method? I think that doesn't throw any error or exception.Is there a way to do so ?

```
this.collector.emit(new Values(id,mns));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the output tuple is expected to contain two fields, but you emit a tuples with a single field.

Storm expects a tuple with two output fields, because you declared the output schema as `new Fields("id","mms"))` in `declareOutputFields(...)`;

You actually answered your question already by yourself. This correct way to emit a 2-field tuple is

```java
this.collector.emit(new Values(id,mns));
```

**Edit:**

You need to step through both tokenized fields at once... Something like this:

```java
String mentionname = tuple.getStringByField("n_name");
String mentionid = tuple.getStringByField("n_id");

String[] idTokens = null;
if(mentionid != null) {
    idTokens = mentionid.split(",");
}
String[] nameTokens = null;
if(mentionname != null){
    nameTokens = mentionname.split(",");
}

for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < idTokens.length && j < nameTokens.lenght; ++i, ++j) {
    this.collector.emit(new Values(idTokens[i].trim(), nameTokens[j].trim()));
}
this.collector.ack(tuple);
```

Comment: But the value I can emit in for each loop is id only. for(String id:mentionid.split(",")){ id = id.trim(); this.collector.emit(new Values(id)); this.collector.ack(tuple);

Comment: Getting error saying : cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable msn.

Comment: I don't know how you changed your code, but this sound like a regular Java programming error not related to Storm... If you are a beginner in Java programming, you should work through a Java text book and start to write simpler code. Using Storm is complex and requires some advanced knowledge.

Comment: I'm not asking you to change my code !  just give me an idea of emitting the strings in a single for loop :) Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: sure I will !  :) @ Matthias J. Sax